# Is there a difference between laminated steel for transformer and inductor?

Tags: transformer, inductor

Does a material (compounds) of laminated-steel core varies if used for transformer vs. inductor. Both for 50Hz. Also is there any other differences?

Comment: Without any additional information, they most likely both use generic "electrical steel".

Comment: @TimWilliams Well, i got some old transformers and inductors. I need to wind an inductor. I took one core that dimensionally should fit for the purpose (power, etc..). I tried to bend one sheet an it breaks so it probably has high silicon content. Is a high silicon content more suitable for transformer or inductor?

Comment: Again, they both likely use generic "electrical steel".  Which is a silicon alloy, yes.

Comment: As a rough general rule, to make an inductor you probably need to use core gaps. Usually not-so for a transformer. The silicon reduces the eddy currents in the laminates without overly reducing magnetic permeability. So, focussing on the laminate type is probably focussing on the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

My laminated-steel specification book had pages and pages of E-H graphs for dozens of different magnetic core specifications.

So yes, steel specified for an inductor (where a field is expected in operation), would be different than the steel specified for a transformer (where the primary field is canceled by the secondary field).

But the primary characteristic of any laminated-core inductor I ever saw (used mostly for florescent light fittings), was that it was the cheapest suitable ferro-magnetic, used in mains-connected applications where power was not important, and efficiency was good enough.

Any random kind of laminated core material will be as good as that.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Analogically with ferrites they also differs when used as transformer vs. inductor so it is probably similar in steel cores.

Answer (score 1):

There are different alloys and different forms of steel (for example, lamination thickness and grain-oriented vs. non-grain-oriented).

For applications where losses are important or frequency content is higher one might expect better grades to be used. The difference in losses (even at mains frequency and for the same lam thickness) between the cheapest and good materials is profound, whereas the net effect of the cost difference is not so much.